# Creating toString method in custom ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I'm creating my own `ArrayList` and stuck in the `toString()` method, can you help me get rid of the comma after printing the last item?

`toString()` method:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(store == null) {
        return "[]";
    } else {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sb.append(store[i].toString() + ", ");
    }

    return "[" + sb.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

`Main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyArrayList<String> fruits = new MyArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("My array list with fruits :)");

    fruits.add("Bananas");
    fruits.add("Apples");
    fruits.add("Pineapple");
    fruits.add("Peaches");
    fruits.add("Pears");
    fruits.add("Plum");

    System.out.println("The list of fruits : " + fruits);

    fruits.clear();

    System.out.println("All fruits have been eaten =) " + fruits);
```

Output:

```
[Bananas, Apples, Pineapple, Peaches, Pears, Plum, ]
```

Comment: You can easily do this by adding an if check for the last element but I would recommend using a stringjoiner instead to avoid the extra condition.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) { sb.append(", "); } sb.append(store[i].toString()); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an if condition to only add the comma if the index `i` is not equals to the last index accepted by the `for` loop

```java
@Override
    public String toString() {  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(store == null) {
        return "[]";
    } else {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sb.append(store[i].toString());
        if(i != size - 1) sb.append(",");
    }

    return "[" + sb.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Concat the comma at the start of the String and start the loop at index 1

```
if(store.length > 0) {
   sb.append(store[0].toString());
}

for (int i = 1; i < store.length; i++) {
   sb.append(", " + store[i].toString());
}
```